# can we put our control on media player while video is playing in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working in windows phone 7.
I am beginner in WPhone.
I have to put the "Record" button on media player.

whenever i will play the video in media player at that time, i have to show recording button on it.

> so, my question is that can we put our user control or the button on media player ?

if yes than how?

show me the code with one media element that plays the video and at that time the button is appearing over it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show what you've tried before and what happened?

Comment: sorry, i have not tried up to now.
but i have to use this functionality in my application.
so, first i want to know that can we add the user control over the Media player or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the button in the native media player which you can launch from your app using  `MediaPlayerLauncher` class, that not possible.

Instead, if you want to show a button over a video playing inside your app, you can do it by using `MediaElement` and placing the `Button` adecuately over it. For example:

```xaml
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Source="/your_video.mp4" />
    <Button Content="REC" Width="90" Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```